# QueryRecord - Get maximum timestamp

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-calcite

I'm developing a simple data ingestion pipeline, and at some point, I'm processing a group of flow files whose content looks something like this:

```
[ 
    {
        "ID" : 1,
        "CREATEDON" : "2019-10-26T18:40:16.000Z",
        "UPDATEDON" : "2019-11-26T18:41:38.000Z",
        ...
    }, {
        "ID" : 2,
        "CREATEDON" : "2019-11-26T18:41:38.000Z",
        "UPDATEDON" : "2019-12-28T11:11:28.000Z",
        ...
    }, ... 
]
```

With the following Avro schema:

```
{
   "type":"record",
   "name":"NiFi_ExecuteSQL_Record",
   "namespace":"any.data",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"ID",
         "type":[
            "null",
            "long"
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"CREATEDON",
         "type":[
            "null",
            {
               "type":"long",
               "logicalType":"timestamp-millis"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"UPDATEDON",
         "type":[
            "null",
            {
               "type":"long",
               "logicalType":"timestamp-millis"
            }
         ]
      },
      ...
   ]
}
```

My current goal is to extract the maximum value of both `CREATEDON` and `UPDATEDON` columns. To do that, I used the `QueryRecord` processor to extract the maximum from each column with the following query:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(createdOn) AS max_createdOn, MAX(updatedOn) AS max_updatedOn 
FROM 
    FLOWFILE
```

But when I run this processor I get the following error:

`Unable to query StandardFlowFileRecord[...] due to java.sql.Timestamp cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`

This makes sense since Apache Calcite represents SQL timestamps as java.lang.Long values and doesn't use java.sql.Timestamp internally, so it's not able to cast it.

The question is: Is there any way to do this without having to create a custom processor?

Comment: May be converting them to milliseconds in a new attribute and then a max(milliseconds) might help?